# AWS EC2 instance stuck on cloud-init

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04, cloud-init

Usually my AutoScaling group spawns instances using Launch Configuration pretty normally but today it gets stuck whilst launching a new instance at the `[cloud-init] checking scripts ...` 
Image for reference, I don't know what is wrong. It just shows me error:Failed [image: Stuck on cloud-init script image]

Comment: Is it one-off incident? What if you kill this instance and let it re-launch?

Comment: @MLu no it doesn't respawn. It stucks again at the same point.

Answer (score 0):

I was installing libpq-dev and it was prompting to restart services.
And traditional `-y` wasn't working, so I tried the command below (to accept defaults) instead and it worked.

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -yq install libpq-dev
```

Reference thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146283/